# Installing PostGIS Manager and RT Sql Layer plugins in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

PostGIS Manager and RT Sql Layer plugins are not visible in my QGIS menu.

I'm running 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both have been replaced by **DB Manager** which covers the functionality of the old plugins.